# Python Tkinter title change from list

Tags: python, tkinter, enumerate

I've tried to simplify the issue with my program through the code below. I can get it to work but am curious as to why it won't work using the method below.

The print values show the first index, yet the function calls the last index.

```
list1 = ["Title_0", "Title_1"]

for i, string in enumerate(list1):
if i == 0:
    print str(i) + ",  " + string # Prints: 0, Title_0
    btn_monty = Button(the_window, text='Monty Python', command = lambda:the_window.title(string))
    #### This also doesn't work ####
    #  btn_monty = Button(the_window, text='Monty Python', command = lambda:the_window.title(list1[i]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `string` within the lambda is [closed](http://effbot.org/zone/closure.htm) on the variable `string`, not the value of `string` . That means that the value for variable `string` is not evaluated until the button is actually called, and when it gets called it uses the latest value of `string` which would be same for both buttons.

You can instead try using default arguments to pass `string` . Example -

```
list1 = ["Title_0", "Title_1"]

for i, strng in enumerate(list1):
    print str(i) + ",  " + strng # Prints: 0, Title_0
    btn_monty = Button(the_window, text='Monty Python', command = lambda new_title=strng:the_window.title(new_title))
```

I also changed the variable to `strng` so that it does not conflict with the `string` module (would be good to avoid any kind of issues in future if you decide to import that module). Also, you should make sure you place the buttons using `grid` or `pack`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I understand now.
Must have accidentally, downvoted, should be fixed now.

Comment: @tom_1230 Glad I could be helpful. Nah , it wasn't you who downvoted, it is someone who is jealous of me :P .